# How to create a table automatically? Using html+angular+typescript

Tags: html, node.js, json, angular, typescript

I'm trying to create a table automatically using Angular and HTML.
I take data from a mysql database using PHP, and Angular can see them thanks to JSON.

In admin.component.html file I create the table using *ngFor in this way:

```
<div fxFlex fxLayoutAlign = "center" style="margin-top: 50px;">
    <table cellpadding="5px">
      <thead>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Tipologia</th>
        <th>Ingredienti</th>
        <th>Allergeni</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let element of piatto;">
          <td>{{element.NomeP}}</td>
          <td>{{element.Tipo}}</td>
          <td *ngFor="let i of element.Ingredienti;" >{{i.NomeI}}</td>
          <td *ngFor="let a of element.Allergeni;" >{{a.NomeA}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

and the output is:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAAsi.png)

I would like to display the table in this way:

```html
<table cellpadding="20px">
  <thead>
    <th>Nome</th>
    <th>Tipologia</th>
    <th>Ingredienti</th>
    <th>Allergeni</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tagliolini al salmone</td>
      <td>Primo</td>
      <td>Pasta, Salmone</td>
      <td>Glutine, Pesce</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Macedonia</td>
      <td>Dessert</td>
      <td>Mela, Banana</td>
      <td>Frutta</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I do?

Here there is "piatto" definition from piatto.models.ts:

```
export class Piatto{
CodP !: number;
NomeP !: string;
Tipo !: string;
Ingredienti !: Array<any>;
Allergeni !: Array<any>; }
```

And here there is what "piatto" contains:

```js
(2) [{…}, {…}]
  0:
    Allergeni: Array(2)
      0: {CodA: "1", NomeA: "Glutine"}
      1: {CodA: "4", NomeA: "Pesce"}
      length: 2
      __proto__: Array(0)
    CodP: "1"
    Ingredienti: Array(2)
      0: {CodI: "3", NomeI: "Pasta", CodA: "1"}
      1: {CodI: "8", NomeI: "Salmone", CodA: "4"}
      length: 2
      __proto__: Array(0)
    NomeP: "Tagliolini al salmone"
    Tipo: "Primo"
    __proto__: Object
  1:
    Allergeni: Array(1)
      0: {CodA: "8", NomeA: "Frutta a guscio"}
      length: 1
      __proto__: Array(0)
    CodP: "5"
    Ingredienti: Array(2)
      0: {CodI: "9", NomeI: "Mela", CodA: "8"}
      1: {CodI: "10", NomeI: "Banana", CodA: null}
      length: 2
      __proto__: Array(0)
    NomeP: "Macedonia"
    Tipo: "Dessert"
    __proto__: Object
  length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `*ngFor` is placed on the `td` tag it ends up creating multiple `td` tags, one for each element within `element.Ingredienti` and `element.Allergeni`. What you want is to display the whole `element.Ingredienti` array within a single `td`. So generating some other tag within a single `td` is the way to go.

Something like this should solve your issue

```html
    <td> <span *ngFor="let i of element.Ingredienti;" >{{i.NomeI}} </span> </td>
    <td> <span *ngFor="let a of element.Allergeni;" >{{a.NomeA}} </span> </td>
```